# Paypal Integration for creating merchant accounts by redirect to paypal and redirect back to Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, redirect, paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am having a Rails 4 Application where I need to make a sub-merchants accounts on paypal with redirect to paypal from Application and after doing same redirect back to the Application.

Answer (score 2):

If I am not wrong then you want to connect you all merchant with single account which will be your company account, if so then all merchant who wants to accept payment into their bank account into their bank account through your application then you should go with **Adaptive Accounts**

***Adaptive Accounts :*** Use the Adaptive Accounts API to build applications that create and manage PayPal accounts. Merchants and developers can use the API to create PayPal accounts, add payment methods to accounts, and verify a PayPal account status.
Here is documentation please refer.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/adaptive-accounts/

Comment: Thanks @SSR. It seems like same what I was looking for. But is couldn't find  snippet or tutorial for this which can help me in better way. If you have some URL link or some snippet kindly share, it would be great of you. Thanks again.